# Invoke cockpit APIs to obtain stats for network, CPU, and memory

Tags: http, cockpit

I've installed the base `cockpit` package on an Ubuntu server, and I'd like to gather network, CPU, and memory stats onto one page. Is there a way to invoke the APIs to obtain - either whole HTML document or JSON data samples, and use them?